# Displaying array in JLabel - Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am trying to display an array in Java Swing using JLabel. This code only prints the first underscore ( _ ). Not sure what I am doing wrong. I tried playing with the bounds but that didn't help.

```
dashes = new JLabel();
//display underscores for each letter in word
for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
    temp[i] = "_ ";
    dashes.setText(temp[i]);
    dashes.setBounds(100, 100, 97, 33);
    frame.getContentPane().add(dashes);
}
```

Comment: You assign `"_ "` to `temp[i]`, then overwrite the value in `dashes` on every iteration.  It appears you either you need to append the text, or create a new instance for `dashes` on each iteration.

Comment: How do I append the text? @MarcL.

Comment: To be honest, I answered before I saw this was a Java question...darned C-like languages!  Based on what you seem to be trying to do: rather than appending the text, try moving `dashes = new JLabel();` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to append the text like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();  
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) { // initialize the array
                    temp[i] = "_ ";
                    sb.append(temp[i]);
                        dashes.setText(sb.toString());
                        dashes.setBounds(100, 100 + add, 97, 33);
                        frame.getContentPane().add(dashes);
                }
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are really trying to do. Show an example. Such as, if temp[0] is "abcde" and temp[1] is "defgh", what should the text in dashes be?

Comment: You need to update `dashes` in the loop, build the `String` within the loop and when your done, update the components. Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify